# MongoDB - Fast Grouping/Aggregation of huge data set

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The documents in my MongoDb look like this:

```js
{
    "Property A" : X,
    "Property B" : ..,
    "Property C" : [
        {
            "Price" : "1",
            "SubPropertyB" : "x1",
        },
        {
            "Price" : "2",
            "SubPropertyB" : "x2"
        },
        {
            "Price" : "3",
            "SubPropertyB" : "x3",
        }  
    ]
},
{
    "Property A" : X
    "Property B" : ..,
    "Property C" :  [
        {
            "Price" : "4",
            "SubPropertyB" : "x4",
        },
        {
            "Price" : "5",
            "SubPropertyB" : "x5",
        },
        {
            "Price" : "6",
            "SubPropertyB" : "x6",
        }   
    ]
},
{
    "Property A" : Y,
    "Property B" : ..,
    "Property C" : [
        {
            "Price" : "1",
            "SubPropertyB" : "y1",
        },
        {
            "Price" : "2",
            "SubPropertyB" : "y2",
        },
        {
            "Price" : "3",
            "SubPropertyB" : "y3",
        }   
    ]
},
{
    "Property A" : Y,
    "Property B" : ..,
    "Property C" : [
        {
            "Price" : "4",
            "SubPropertyB" : "y4",
        },
        {
            "Price" : "5",
            "SubPropertyB" : "y5",
        },
        {
            "Price" : "6",
            "SubPropertyB" : "y6",
        }   
    ]
}
```

Now I want to group this documents by PropertyA. For my example, I will find two groups with each two documents. After this, I have to get the document with the lowest price for every group. For my example, I would expect a result with two documents which should look like this:

```js
{
    "Property A" : X,
    "Property B" : ..,
    "Property C" :    
    "Price" : "1",
    "SubPropertyB" : "x1",
},
{
    "Property A" : y,
    "Property B" : ..,
    "Property C" :    
    "Price" : "1",
    "SubPropertyB" : "y1",
}
```

How can I realize this with the aggregation framework in MongoDb (How will look such a query), so that the search will perform very fast?

Comment: Can you please elaborate and also tell what is the expected final answer after the query has run?

Comment: please use proper indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you want to use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) in order to group and find your "best price":

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  // Match your documents first
  { "$match": { "PropertyB": "xyz" } },

  // Unwind the array to de-normalize as individual documents
  { "$unwind": "$PropertyC" },

  // Group by "PropertyA" with the max price
  { "$group": {
     "_id": "$PropertyA",
     "price": { "$max": "$PropertyC.Price" }
  }}

])
```

Naturally, the field to index there is "PropertyB" as that is what you are doing your initial filter on with [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/).

Not sure what your definition of "best price" is but it is either [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) for highest or [**`$min`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) for lowest. Please note that these values should be numbers as lexical sorted strings are likely to produce unexpected results.

See also the [Aggregation Operator Reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/).

Comment: Thanks for this useful answer. What I have forgotten, in my result document I would like to have not only the value of the id and the price, but also the values of all the other properties of the document (in my example PropertyA, PropertyB, PropertyC.Price, PropertyC.Subproperty). How I have to do this?

Comment: @user3703586 What exactly do you mean from this? It is not clear from your question which values you want to choose and how? Are they all the $max value? Are some $min or $first or $last? You could edit your question to make it clear what you want to do and notify me of the change when you have made it.

Comment: I edit my question. I hope it is now more clear what I want to do! Thanks!

Comment: This was your original question that was answered before you drastically changed your question: "Now I have to find the document with the best price over all documents, where PropertyB == xyz!". On Stack Overflow you have **one** question to ask and people answer it. If you want to ask an additional question the ask another question by posting another question. Such a radical change is not cool. I can answer you but I will not as such a change is rude. Ask another question.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake and that I did not formulate my question correctly in my first post. In the future I will improve. I will ask another question.